# use if with NSinteger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsinteger

I WANT to use NSinteger variable *strength  in my code with if condition but it's not work.. :(

```
if(strength == 11){
}
```

How can i use if with NSInteger*

Comment: Why with a *? NSInteger is not an object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NSInteger` is a primitive value type; you don't really need to use pointers. So your declaration should read

```
NSInteger strength;
```

And not

```
NSInteger *strength;
```

However if you *do* need to use a pointer to an `NSInteger` (that is, `NSInteger *`) for some reason, then you need to dereference the pointer to get the value:

```
if (*strength == 11) {
}
```

but from what I see, I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you must be adding an * when you declare your `strength` variable. You shouldn't have it because `NSInteger` is a primitive type.

[Why don't I declare NSInteger with a *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014053/why-dont-i-declare-nsinteger-with-a)