# How to compare a NSNumber in an if

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to:

```
if (myNSNumber == 1)
{
 ...
}
```

This doesn't seem to build

The object:

Comment: Title doesn't seem right. A NSInteger test would compile, I think you mean NSNumber.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If *myNSNUmber* is `NSNumber`, your code should read,

```
if ([myNSNumber intValue] == 1) {
    ...
}
```

If it is `NSInteger`, you can directly compare it with an integer literal. Because `NSInteger` is a primitive data type.

```
if (myNSNumber == 1) {
    ...
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you don't have `*` in your declaration. Your `NSInteger` declarations should read,

```
NSInteger myNSNUmber; // RIGHT
NSInteger *myNSNUmber; // WRONG, NSInteger is not a struct, but it is a primitive data type.
```

The following is based on @BoltClock's answer, which he recently posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791175/use-if-with-nsinteger/4791195#4791195)

---

However if you do need to use a pointer to an NSInteger (that is, NSInteger *) for some reason, then you need to dereference the pointer to get the value:

```
if (*myNSNUmber == 11) {
}
```

---

Comment: NSNumber is a struct, so you cannot compare it to an integer. What Simon has posted is correct.

Comment: `myNSNumber` is NSInteger or `NSNumber`? If It is `NSInteger` make sure you don't have `*` in the declaration.

Answer (score 3):

NSInteger is normally a plain int type so your code should work fine.

if myNSNumber a NSNumber object (as variable name suggests) then you should extract its int value:

```
if ([myNSNumber intValue] == 1)
{
 ...
}
```