# Getting "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id." when requesting RestKit loadObjectsAtResourcePath

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, restkit

I'm trying to deserialise JSON data into my iPhone application using RestKit's RKObjectManager.

My current issue is the app crashes with a :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Course 0x6e71b10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'
```

when I call:

```
[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/courses" delegate:nil];
```

My domain class - Course.h looks like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>



@interface Course : NSObject  {

}

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger *id;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

-(id)initWithIdAndName: (NSInteger *)inId inName:(NSString *)inName;
@end
```

and the Course.m looks like

```
#import "Course.h"
#import "NSDictionary+RKAdditions.h"


@implementation Course {

}
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize id = _id;

- (id)initWithIdAndName:(NSInteger *)inId inName:(NSString *)inName {
    _name = inName;
    _id = inId;
    return self;

}

#pragma mark NSCoding Protocol


- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
{
[encoder encodeInteger:[self id] forKey:@"id"];
[encoder encodeObject:[self name] forKey:@"name"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
{
if ( ![super init] )
    return nil;

[self setId:[decoder decodeIntForKey:@"id"]];
[self setName:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"]];


return self;
}

@end
```

The Json data retrieved from the server is

```
{"courses":[{"id":1,"name":"course 1"},{"id":2,"name":"course 2"}]}
```

And the RKObjectManager is invoked using the following code:

```
RKObjectMapping* courseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Course class]];
[courseMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
[courseMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];


RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://firstbit/of/url"];

[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:courseMapping forKeyPath:@"courses"];
[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/endpoint" delegate:nil];
```

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the id property to something like courseId to avoid possible naming clash.

Comment: I don't think this was the issue, but should have been NSInteger and not NSInteger * anyways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014053/why-dont-i-declare-nsinteger-with-a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might help others, but I had this problem and the reason was that I was using NSInteger in my object definition. [RestKit cannot map to NSInteger, only NSNumber](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping).

Comment: Are you sure they don't somehow account for this? I successfully map to NSIntegers in many places on my current project.

Comment: @Kyle I agree with Alexander, I don't think RestKit supports mapping to primitive types. So, for example one has to map JSON booleans to NSNumber *

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error, although my issue was simply forgetting to remove the @dynamic directive with @synthesize in changing my test from using CoreData.

---

Comment: Thanks for posting this comment, I also went from a core data model to using just the object mapping and i forgot to switch the properties back to @synthesize.

Answer (score 3):

I am posting this as an alternative answer. The answers so far are totally correct. There is one more permutation that took me awhile to find. The simulator may have cached a bundle resource for the program. If this bundle resource is out of date you can get a conflict. The easiest solution: "uninstall" the app from the simulator (and potentially other apps that may have  a same name bundle). Once I did this, I found the real issue immediately as I had not correctly attached my bundle to the parent project form an sdk project.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking the JSON your getting back is valid & in the format (keys  / value types), you expect - I've had this exact same issue with RESTKit before

I use 'JSON Validator' & 'Visual JSON', both free on the Mac App Store

Alternatively make sure your CoreData Entity allows *to-many* mappings for **courses**

Comment: Yes, Visual JSON was a great one! In nested JSONs one gets on the wrong path quite quickly -  the tree view helps to get things right.

Answer (score 1):

This one probably seems obvious, but it got me for two days...

Make sure all the classes in your RKObjectMappings are correct! It was one little typo where I was using the parent class for a nested element's mapping, in a line of code I never looked at because I assumed it was definitely correct, and it was making the whole thing crash.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this error can come up due to a number of issues that have to do with attribute *or relationship* mappings.

This includes typos in any of your attribute names.

Remember, an attribute or relationship mapping isn't correct unless it **aligns with your API**. For example, I just ran into this error because of something like the following:

Each `Restaurant` model has a foreign key relationship to the `Location` model.

```
[restaurantMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"location" toKeyPath:@"location" withMapping:locationMapping]];
```

But the API I'm using returns something like the following JSON data for a `Restaurant` object:

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "resource_uri": "http://example.com/api/v1/restaurants/42",
    "location": "http://example.com/api/v1/locations/987"
}
```

RestKit is looking for a *full* response like the following:

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "resource_uri": "http://example.com/api/v1/restaurants/42",
    "location": {
        "id": 987,
        "resource_uri": "http://example.com/api/v1/locations/987"
    }
}
```

Note the different `location` value.

I imagine you could also alter RestKit to handle former API response, but that mismatch of expectations could cause this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer state that RestKit cannot map to NSInteger which I found it's not entirely true because I've encountered the the same problem recently and solved it just by remove the * of the `NSInteger` property.

I use `@property(nonatomic) NSInteger id;` instead of  `@property(nonatomic) NSInteger *id;`