# Objective-c: why is 0 + 20 = 160?

Tags: objective-c

A strange thing is happening in my app. I have the following `NSInteger`:

```
NSInteger *contentStart;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, I did:

```
contentStart=0;
```

Then in another method, I did:

```
contentStart = contentStart + 20;
NSLog(@"%d", (int)contentStart);
```

The output is 160 instead of 20!

I tried everything, I even tried `contentStart+=20`, which gives the same result.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? I'm going crazy with this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Try to `NSLog` the value of `contentStart` before `contentStart = contentStart + 20`

Comment: i did, it shows the value `0`

Comment: %d = not a int. Look at your at format specifiers.

Comment: I found an error. You should use `NSInteger contentStart` instead of `NSInteger *contentStart`.

Comment: What do you mean by `didLoad`? Is it some custom method, or actual overriden `- (void)viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are adding `20 * sizeof(NSInteger)` as `contentStart` is of type `NSInteger *`, so you are doing pointer arithmetic.

I assume you are building for 64-bit where `sizeof(NSInteger) == 8`.

Answer (score 3):

`NSInteger*` is pointer at `NSInteger` variable.
When you do `contentStart + 20` that mean, that you move pointer at 20 `NSInteger`'s. Look's like you have 64bit environment. In 64 environment one `NSInteger` require 8 bytes. So 8 * 20 = 160;
That's why value at `contentStart` changed at 160 instead 20.

This is calculation with pointers.

Comment: so if OP were to `[NSLog(@"%d", (int)&contentStart)];`, would that work?  By dereferencing the pointer?

Comment: @MattyAyOh, no, it will print trimmed to 32 bits `contentsStart`'s address. `int8_t* contentStart;` also will give expected result.

Comment: Pardon my pestering-- I could probably spin up a sample app to figure this stuff out... but I already have SO open :)
Okay I got the first part, for the second part, why would a pointer to int8_t work but not an NSInteger when dereferencing?

Comment: Like trojanfoe wrote: `sizeof(NSInteger) == 8`. And `sizeof(int8_t) == 1` - one byte. So moving pointer at 20 `int8_t` will move pointer at 20 bytes. But when you do arithmetics you  should use normal variables, not pointers. Using pointers may be useful for example when you parse binary data flow for archiving or encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Because of sizeof(NSInteger) is 8 bytes, you are shifting your pointer by 20 * sizeof(NSInteger) which is equal 160

Answer (score -2):

Replace

`NSInteger *contentStart;`

With

`NSInteger contentStart;`

And you're good to go :)

**Explanation**

NSInteger is a primitive type, which means it can be stored locally on the stack. You don't need to use a pointer to access it.

For those who wants a full explanation, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014053/why-dont-i-declare-nsinteger-with-a/1014078#1014078) answer

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd explain why using a pointer causes this problem.

Comment: @Cy-4AH because you are printing the address of the pointer, not the value it  points to.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't really understand what the pointer means. but now i do.